# Combining ng-if together

Tags: html, angularjs, user-interface, ng-show, angular-ng-if

I want my two ng-if to work together instead of separately. If both are true then only show the last one that is true. My code looks like this right now.

```
<div>   
    <img ng-src="{{img(myColor)}}" ng-if="myColor">

    <img ng-src="{{img(myColor2)}}" ng-if="myColor2">
</div>
```

However, this just stacks them on top of each other when both ng-if become true. Is there a way to only show one at a time without css

Answer (score 3):

I might be very late to suggest a solution. But I assume you can do it with && bitwise operator.

Below is the sample code:

```html
<div>   
    <img ng-src="{{img(myColor)}}" ng-if="myColor && !myColor2">

    <img ng-src="{{img(myColor2)}}" ng-if="myColor && myColor2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need more complicated logic than what simple markup can provide. Why not just use a scope function that sets the color, then use consolidated markup.

```
<div>
  <img ng-src="{{img(color)}}" ng-if="color">
</div>
```

And in your javascript

```
$scope.setColor = function() {
  // Something that determines what color to set.
  $scope.color = ...;
};
```

Comment: I have clarified the question, when both are true I only want to show one of them - the latest ng-if. How do I do this?

Comment: @jebmarcus - what do you mean by "latest"?

Comment: I meant that they switch back and forth. If the first ng-if is true first, then second ng-if becomes true, I want <img ng-src="{{img(myColor2)}}"> to be shown. Almost like a toggle